# Cannot edit a form where "setData" has been set - Symfony3

Tags: forms, controller, symfony

I have a `function` in my `controller` that can let me edit a restaurant page.

I needed to `setData` some values in order to keep them from the showing view to the editing view, and I needed it on the `city` and `zipCode` field.

```
$editForm->get('cityName')->setData($restaurant->getCity()->getName());
$editForm->get('cityZipCode')->setData($restaurant->getCity()->getZipCode());
```

But I cannot edit anymore my form once I used `setData` as this error message appears

```
You cannot change the data of a submitted form.
```

Here is the controller part

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Restaurant $restaurant)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($restaurant);
    $editForm = $this->createForm(RestaurantType::class, $restaurant);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    $editForm->get('cityName')->setData($restaurant->getCity()->getName());
    $editForm->get('cityZipCode')->setData($restaurant->getCity()->getZipCode());

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $cityManager = $this->container->get('admin.city_manager');
        $cityManager->newCity($editForm, $restaurant);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_restaurant_show_fr', array('id' => $restaurant->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('admin/restaurant/edit.html.twig', array(
        'restaurant' => $restaurant,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and here is the `FormType`

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label'                 => 'Nom',
            ))
            ->add('latitude', NumberType::class, array(
                'label'                 => 'Latitude',
            ))
            ->add('longitude', NumberType::class, array(
                'label'                 => 'Longitude',
            ))
            ->add('address', TextType::class, array(
                'label'                 => 'Adresse',
            ))
            ->add('cityName', TextType::class, array(
                'mapped'                => false,
                'label'                 => 'Ville'
            ))
            ->add('cityZipCode', TextType::class, array(
                'mapped'                => false,
                'label'                 => 'Code Postal'
            ))
}
```

If you have anything that could help me and fix that problem, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create the form and have called the `handleRequest`, Symfony uses that version of the form for processing (e.g. validation et al).
If you change the form after this, Symfony will not be happy.

Depending on what you are trying to do, and how you have defined your entity/form, either use [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) or [dynamic form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) to handle any changes.

From what you have shown, why not ammend the form to show the city name of the restaurant instead of trying to set it in the controller.
For example;

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label'                 => 'Nom',
        ))
        ->add('latitude', NumberType::class, array(
            'label'                 => 'Latitude',
        ))
        ->add('longitude', NumberType::class, array(
            'label'                 => 'Longitude',
        ))
        ->add('address', TextType::class, array(
            'label'                 => 'Adresse',
        ));

    // if you want the fields not shown on the form
    if (! empty($options['data']->getCity()) {
        $builder->add('cityName', TextType::class, array(
            'data' => $options['data']->getCity()->getName()
            'mapped'                => false,
            'label'                 => 'Ville'
        ))
        ->add('cityZipCode', TextType::class, array(
            'data' => $options['data']->getCity()->getZipCode()
            'mapped'                => false,
            'label'                 => 'Code Postal'
        ));
    }
    // or if you want them there
    $cityName = '';
    $cityZipCode = '';
    if (! empty($options['data']->getCity()) {
        $cityName = $options['data']->getCity()->getName();
        $cityZipCode = $options['data']->getCity()->getZipCode();
    }
        $builder->add('cityName', TextType::class, array(
            'data' => $cityName
            'mapped'                => false,
            'label'                 => 'Ville'
        ))
        ->add('cityZipCode', TextType::class, array(
            'data' => $cityZipCode
            'mapped'                => false,
            'label'                 => 'Code Postal'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rooneyl thanks for your comment. I looked upon `FormEvents` but I'm pretty new and I don't really know how to fix that with formevents. What do you mean by `ammend the forw to show...` if you want I can add the form section to my question if you want to see it?

Comment: @crisscross can you add the part fo the form code that creates the city name/code and I'll try to help you

Comment: Also I wanted to tell you that I use a `service` called `$cityManager`

Comment: oh wait....now when I want to `create` a restaurant I get this error `Call to a member function getName() on null` :(
And it says that the line you showed me is the main error for it.                 'data' => $options['data']->getCity()->getName(),

Comment: @crisscross this is because when editing the form has a full restaurant object, and on create it has an empty object. You can either do a check if the form to test if city exists and then add it or use validation groups to control your form rendering. I'll update my answer in abit

Comment: Ok I will check on the docs. But would appreciated your update too to understand it fully. Thanks @Rooneyl

Comment: You second method works! :) (there is a `)` missing that I added) The first method I couldn't understand how to implement it and where to do it so I implemented your second method :)